# Current measurement in MOSFET circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, analog, current-measurement, fet

In this circuit, the drain current needs to be calculated when S1 opens and S2 closes and remain in this position for long time. In this position, the transistor is in cutoff region i.e Id=0. But the given answer is -25 microA. Please help me with a solution. 
[image: Aspect ratio=2]

Comment: Since this is homework, you need an attempt at a solution, please provide one. If not there is a high chance that this question will be closed

Comment: What assumption are you making about how the body of the transistor is connected? And, yes, you need to show all of your work.